# How to rank a vector using a second vector as a tie breaker?

Tags: r, sorting, ranking

I need to implement a ranking algorithm for numeric vectors. I don't know if it's possible to do it using functions like rank(), order() or sort() in R, or if I should hard-code it. Either way, I could not do it.

The algorithm works as follows:

Let x = (x_1,x_2...,x_n) and y = (y_1,y_2,...y_n) be two vectors.
We need to build the vector z composed of the ranked elements of x this way:

1. `If x_i < x_j then z_i < z_j`
2. `If x_i = x_j then`

   - `z_i < z_j if y_i < y_j`
   - `z_i > z_j if y_i > y_j`
   - `z_i = z_j if y_i = y_j`
3. `If x_i is NA (missing) then`

   - `z_i > z_j if z_j is not NA`
   - `z_i = z_j if z_j is NA`

For example, if x = (30,15,27,49,15) and y = (12,11,10,9,8) then z = (4,2,3,5,1)

I think I could use `order(order(x,y, na.last=T))` and in fact it worked as long as the ties in x do not tie in y as well. If that's the case, then `order()` will rank them in order of appearance instead of leaving them tied.

For example, if x = (30,15,27,49,15) and y = (12,8,10,9,8) then `order(order(x,y, na.last=T))` will output z = (4,1,3,5,2) instead of z = (4,1,3,5,1) or another z (such as (3,1,2,4,1)) that respects step 2.

I could not escape that. How can I proceed?

Comment: hmmm... i kind of got lost in what is step2.. but i guess rank(x,y,ties.method="min") gives you one of the intended output.. maybe play with that more?

Comment: Step 2 is when you actually use the second vector as a tie breaker. Suppose the i,j and k-th elements of x are equal. Then their rank will depend on the order of the i, j and k-th elements of y. If they're also equal in y, then they must be equal in the end.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** I think version 1 is best.  Versions 2 and 3 were early ideas that are not as good, but I leave them here in case they are useful to anyone.

---

Unfortunately `rank` does not provide the ability to break ties using a second vector (a useful capability that `order` and `sort` *do* allow).

#### Version 1

But, `library(data.table)` provides `frank()` which does the job nicely.

```
x = c(30,15,27,49,15) 
y = c(12,11,10,9,8) 
frank(list(x,y), ties.method = "min")
# [1] 4 2 3 5 1

x = c(30,15,27,49,15) 
y = c(12,8,10,9,8)
frank(list(x,y), ties.method = "min")
# [1] 4 1 3 5 1
```

Note that `frank` also provides another option for `ties.method = "dense"` which may be better for some uses, because it does not skip ranks (i.e. when two values are given rank 1, the next largest gets rank 2, rather than 3) - see below for an example

```
frank(list(x,y), ties.method = "dense")
[1] 3 1 2 4 1
```

#### Version 2

If you want to stick to base R, one simple workaround would be to rank `x * K + y`, where K is any number sufficiently large that adding the largest `y` to any `x*K` cannot change the order:

```
ranky = function(x,y) {
  K = 1 +  max(y) / min(diff(sort(unique(x))))
  rank(x*K + y, ties.method = 'min')
}

ranky(c(30,15,27,49,15), c(12,11,10,9,8) )
# [1] 4 2 3 5 1    
ranky(c(30,15,27,49,15), c(12,8,10,9,8))
# [1] 4 1 3 5 1
```

#### Version 3

Also in base R, you could paste together fixed-width string representations of each and then rank the combined character vector.

```
rank(paste(
      formatC(x, width = 15, flag = "0"), 
      formatC(y, width = 15, flag = "0")), 
     ties.method = 'min')
```

Comment: What was your reasoning? I don't understand why multiply by this big number and add to y. I checked some examples and it worked, but I can't see why.

Comment: If we multiply by a big enough number (K), then so long as the *differences* between `X*K` are very much larger than `y`, then the ranking will depend primarily on the values of `X*K`.  Adding y allows us to then split the difference when `X*K` values are the same, without changing the ordering in other instances.  Of course there are edge cases where this won't work if you have some y or x values that are very large.

Comment: OK, I understand it. You say sort() and order() allow for tie-breaking with a second vector, is it possible to use them effectively here?

Comment: maybe you could figure out a way.  But `sort` and `order` don't provide the `ties.method` option.  So, I don't think it is particularly easy to use them for precisely the result you want.  Maybe someone else will see a way and prove me wrong.  If you want a completely versatile and robust way you might need to look at the source code for rank and order, then adapt the algorithm to give you the best of both worlds (ranking by more than one vector, with ties.method = 'min')

Comment: @Rule184 - I updated answer with a much better option.

Comment: I could not understand the difference between rank() e frank() besides the fact that frank() is _fast rank_. do you think the Version 1 covers all possible cases for this algorithm?

Comment: Yes - I think it does everything you need. Have a look at the help: *"frank is not limited to vectors. It accepts data.tables (and lists and data.frames) as well. It accepts unquoted column names (with names preceded with a - sign for descending order, even on character vectors), for e.g., frank(DT, a, -b, c, ties.method="first") where a,b,c are columns in DT."*

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
f <- function(x, y) {
    data.table(x, y)[order(x, y), r := .I][, r := min(r), .(x, y)]$r
}

f(c(30,15,27,49,15), c(12,11,10,9,8))
#[1] 4 2 3 5 1

f(c(30,15,27,49,15), c(12,8,10,9,8))
#[1] 4 1 3 5 1
```

Or what should be a faster version:

```
f <- function(x, y) {
    DT <- setindex(data.table(x, y), x, y)[order(x, y), r := .I]

    if (uniqueN(data.table(x, y))==DT[, .N]) 
        DT$r
    else 
        DT[,r := min(r), .(x, y)]$r
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function to do this:

```
my_order <- function(x,y){
  a <- rank(x,ties.method = "first")
  b <- `class<-`(names(which(table(x)>1)),class(x))
  c(apply(outer(x,b,'=='),2,function(m)a[m]<<-a[m][rank(y[m])]))
  a
}
```

The reason for the `apply` function is because we can have more than one repeated value:

```
x = c(30,15,27,49,15) ;
y = c(12,8,10,9,8) 
my_order(x,y)
[1] 4 1 3 5 1

my_order(c(2,1,1,2),c(6,4,2,6))
[1] 3 2 1 3
```

compare with

```
order(order(c(2,1,1,2),c(6,4,2,6)))
[1] 3 2 1 4
```